# iphone6 to play video inline on Web page

Tags: javascript, video

I have seen on some websites when they are viewed on iPhone 6 the videos play inline rather than going to full screen in mobile safari, how is this achieved?

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 [`<video>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video) element is most likely how this is achieved. Cross-compatibility is something to think about, though, because older browsers won't support this object.